# Is there any difference b/w IS NULL in MySQL and MS SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

What is the difference b/w IS NULL functions in  MySQL and MS SQL.

(@VendorID IS NULL OR @VendorID = Contract.VendorID) this is the MS SQL statement.If I want this in MySql do I need to change the syntax.And one more thing is What is IF Null?

Comment: [IS NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) & [ISNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`IS NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) in `MySQL`.

[`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) is a function that will return another value if the field is `NULL`.  This is SQL Servers equivalent of `ISNULL`

For example:

```
 IFNULL(VendorId, 0)
```

Will return 0 if the VendorId is null

You can also use [`COALESCE`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php) which will return the first non `NULL` value:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Field1, Field2, Field3)
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that `COALESCE(VendorId, 0)` is the ANSI standard?

Comment: @Sam - added it a COALESCE example.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no difference at all, this will work fine in mysql query window as well.

Answer (score 1):

`Is NULL` is ANSI standard and should behave anywhere the same.